# How to hide optional fields for autoform in simple-schema

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have created a Schema with Simple-Schema package from aldeed like:

```
// Schema definition of this content type
Conditional_Schema = new SimpleSchema({

  item_type: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Type',
    allowedValues: ['Product', 'File', 'Comment']
  },

  product_name: {
    label: 'Product',
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      group: '02_Product'
      // this field should be available and shown
      // in form only when 
      // this.field("item_type").value === "Product"
    }
  },

  product_price: {
    label: 'Price',
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      group: '02_Product'
      // this field should be available and shown
      // in form only when 
      // this.field("item_type").value === "Product"
    }
  }

});
```

How may I specify a condition to the schema so that the above fields for `Product Details` are only shown in form when the value `Product` is selected **without** having a template helper (`afFieldValueContains`).

Comment: It's a current feature request: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/924 Right now you have to use `afFieldValueIs`

Comment: Hi @fuzzybabybunny - Do you know how I have to notate that inside the schema definition?